# hibernate.cfg.xml and applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a small application using Spring3, Hibernate4 and JSF2.

So far in my application I do not have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, I have used Spring `applicationContext.xml` for scanning classes and annotations for Entity class.

*applicationContext.xml*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />
    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:TEST" />
        <property name="user" value="scott" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.test.model.Employees</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>            
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What I would like to do is add `hibernate.cfg.xml` into my application, I know it is not mandatory if I have `applicaionContext.xml` exists.

The reason why I would want to include is because I would like to specify the following in `hibernate.cfg.xml` in order to resolve the issue of

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException:
   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlToken
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932138/weblogic-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-hqltoken) for details of exceptions I am getting

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory">
</property>
```

As I already have the following in `applicationContext.xml`, how best I could use `hibernate.cfg.xml`? Any help is highly appreciable.

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.test.model.Request</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

*Update 1*

```
Error creating bean with name 'requestDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies
failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory 
 net.test.request.dao.RequestDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
 bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource 
 [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
 nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not 
  instantiate QueryTranslatorFactory: 
  org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set *hibernate.query.factory_class* property using Spring's application.xml like this?:

```
<bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        ...
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            </props>            
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It seems to me that this should work without explicitly using hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: I have added org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory in applicationContext.xml. However I have few exceptions when I deploy. I have added exceptions as Update 1 by editing my question.

Comment: Oh yes this worked, thanks a lot. For Hibernate4 it should be like `org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory`. Once you saved my day, been trying to resolve this for since afternoon. Appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that thay changed package where ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory is located on org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic. See my updates.

Comment: Yes it has been changed. Thanks again.